# Allow access through AJAX only not directly?

Tags: ajax, http

Is there a way to only allow calls to come into a script through AJAX and not allow end users to access the page directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Direct Access To File Called By ajax Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756591/prevent-direct-access-to-file-called-by-ajax-function)

Comment: Very similar to this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671276/restrict-ajax-call-origin/8671370#8671370 - see my answer there.

Comment: Thanks! Search for a while just wasn't sure what to search for.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Nope.

Long answer: AJAX is absolutely similar to "direct" access to the url. There is literally no difference between them. Actually there is: only one header that can be forged easily